# We're unable to send the password reset email in Magento 2

Tags: email, magento-2.1.3, password, password-recovery

When i try to reset my password by using forgot password link, i get this error.

```
We're unable to send the password reset email
```

Comment: Are other emails (like customer registration, newsletter signup etc.) being sent?

Comment: No. There is no email is sending.

Comment: How to solve it ?

Comment: Have you migrated data from m1 to m2 or for new customer, you got this error

Comment: Which areas are you getting this error ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on live server you need to enable sending emails and if you are on local server then you can achieve it by installing some Magento 2 extensions which are working perfectly.

Some of the tested extensions for custom SMTP are listed below:

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

First you need to send testing mail if it will work then you can go further and if this will not work then you need to debug like store id and area etc
do let me know if you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since no emails are being sent from the website, it means that the server has no service configured for sending emails.

You can either ask your server's administrator to enable SMTP service or you can install a custom (free or paid) SMTP extension in your Magento.

Some of the tested extensions for custom SMTP are listed below:

- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/ (**Free**)
- https://store.webkul.com/SMTP-Configurator-Magento2.html (**Paid**)

Please let me know if something is not clear.